# Send Upload Image data to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, save

I want to send data to database so when user upload image all of his image data saves in database in mysql please tell me what should I do to make it work .

When User Upload image he can see this type of data after successful upload

```
Upload: wallpaper.jpg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 8.7072027134876 kB
Stored in: upload/wallpaper.jpg
```

So I want to save this data in database like Type in type column, size in size column and similarly stored in data in storelink

Here is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
$username = "root";
    $password = "123";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

    $selected = mysql_select_db("user", $dbhandle);

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] <= 200000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))




  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 10024) . " kB<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

**Here is HTML Code**

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see no queries in your code, what have you tried?

Comment: yeah that's why I am asking what code should I add

Answer (score 0):

You can't store images files in MYSQL database. what you can store is texts so the you better worry about recording the image URL ( address where the image is stored) instead of worring about storing image in database.

Images are stored in the server hard disk. read about image uploading built in functions in PHP.

Comment: Yeah I am taking about image data not image itself I know database can't save images Image will be saved in folder called "uploads" I want to save image url please tell me the code and method